# how to copy a sheet from a workbook to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

```
Sub copySheets()
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Dim wkb As Workbook
        Dim wks As Worksheet
        Dim wkb, wkb1 As Workbook
        Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim fd As FileDialog
        Dim FileName As String
        'Dim wks As Worksheet
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'Set c = Sheets("formulas").Range("j19:j148").Find(ws.Name, lookat:=xlWhole)
        'If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Sheets(c.Value).Select
        'the number of the button chosen
        Dim FileChosen As Integer
        FileChosen = fd.Show
        fd.Title = "Choose workbook"
        fd.InitialFileName = "c:\wise owl\"
        fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        'show Excel workbooks and macro workbooks
        fd.Filters.Clear
        'fd.Filters.Add "Excel workbooks", "*.xlsx"
        fd.Filters.Add "Excel macros", "*.xlsm"
        fd.FilterIndex = 1
        fd.ButtonName = "Choose this file"
        If FileChosen <> -1 Then
        'didn't choose anything (clicked on CANCEL)
        MsgBox "No file opened"
        Else
        'get file, and open it (NAME property
        'includes path, which we need)
        FileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        Workbooks.Open (FileName)
        'End If
        Set c = Sheets("formulas").Range("j19:j148").Find(ws.Name, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
            'need to copy from just opened worksheet to a file called "estimate test"
            'Public Sub copyworksheet()
                Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
                Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
                Set wks = wkb.Sheets(c.Value)
                wks.Copy After:=wkb1.Sheets(wkb1.Sheets.Count)
            End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This macro copy the worksheet called `abc` from the opened workbook to workbook *Book2*, adapt it to your code.

```
Public Sub copyworksheet()
    Dim wkb, wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\users\me\Documents\Book2.xls")
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets("abc")
    wks.Copy After:=wkb1.Sheets(wkb1.Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: im getting a next without a for error. tried to paste the code here but its too long. any suggestions on how i can post the code?

Comment: ok, i edited the post so that the current code shows the for next error. can you assist?

Comment: @DanM Look for this line `'End If` after  `Workbooks.Open (FileName)` and remove the `'`

Comment: did that, now im getting a run time error 9, subscript out of range error. the offending line is Set c = Sheets("formulas").Range("j19:j148").Find(ws.Name, lookat:=xlWhole). maybe i need to put the workbook name in the sheets line above?